# An unhandled exception occurred: D:\workspace-angular\demoapp1 contains both .browserslistrc and browserslist

Tags: node.js, angular

when I **serve** the angular project the following error occurred.

[An unhandled exception occurred: D:\workspace-angular\demoapp1 contains both .browserslistrc and browserslist
See "C:\Users\TTLJSR\AppData\Local\Temp\ng-05qxjF\angular-errors.log" for further details.][1]

````
    at D:\workspace-angular\demoapp1\node_modules\browserslist\node.js:333:15
    at eachParent (D:\workspace-angular\demoapp1\node_modules\browserslist\node.js:49:18)
    at Object.findConfig (D:\workspace-angular\demoapp1\node_modules\browserslist\node.js:301:20)
    at Function.loadConfig (D:\workspace-angular\demoapp1\node_modules\browserslist\node.js:219:37)
    at browserslist (D:\workspace-angular\demoapp1\node_modules\browserslist\index.js:411:31)
    at new BuildBrowserFeatures (D:\workspace-angular\demoapp1\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-angular\src\utils\build-browser-features.js:18:34)
    at generateWebpackConfig (D:\workspace-angular\demoapp1\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-angular\src\utils\webpack-browser-config.js:37:34)
    at async generateBrowserWebpackConfigFromContext (D:\workspace-angular\demoapp1\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-angular\src\utils\webpack-browser-config.js:138:20)
    at async Object.generateI18nBrowserWebpackConfigFromContext (D:\workspace-angular\demoapp1\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-angular\src\utils\webpack-browser-config.js:87:20)
    at async setup (D:\workspace-angular\demoapp1\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-angular\src\dev-server\index.js:76:47) ```


 


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/e9i18.png
````

Comment: What version of Angular?  Also you can try to remove one of them.

Comment: Angular CLI: 10.0.3
Node: 12.16.3
OS: win32 x64

Answer (score 8):

Delete the newer file, [browserslistrc]

These two files appear identical. I encountered this when I updated my project to the latest Angular version, then restored the project from a backup location. After deleting the newer file [browserslistrc], this error went away. I think this is what Mahendra Kumar was getting at, too.

Comment: An unhandled exception occurred: Unknown browser query `basedir=$(dirname "$(echo "$0" | sed -e 's`. Maybe you are using old Browserslist or made typo in query.
See "C:\Users\TTLJSR\AppData\Local\Temp\ng-jHGoRN\angular-errors.log" for further details.    ------ the above issue is arrive after deleting the file

Answer (score 3):

**Notice, that was for Angular Project**

You can solve your problem by removing both
browserslist error and .browserslistrc files.

**re-build and run your app**

*npm run start* or *yarn serve* for my case

Answer (score 3):

Simple solution that worked for me =>
Remove both **browserslist** error and **.browserslistrc** files.

re-build and run your app using command
**ng serve**